# How to retieve fresh data after Datatable.reload()?

Tags: datatable

After changing the url and issuing a reload(), the data retrieved with data() is the "old" one, corresponding to previous url. Here is the sample code :

```
dTable2.ajax.url("newUrl.com").load();
dTable2.draw();   // new data is drawn 

var dTable = $(myClass).DataTable();
var dt = dTable.data();    
// dt still contains data of previous url
```

defining a function to be fired on reload event still sends "old" data :

`dTable2.ajax.reload( function (json){ myfunc(json) } )`

What am I doing wrong ?

It works when run within drawCallback function, but this gets executed too often.  This statement return fresh data :
`

```
this.api.data()
```

Comment: You can intercept the new JSON data using the DataTables [`xhr` event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr). That should not typically fire as frequently as a `draw`. I think you cannot do what you are trying in the question because the `load()` is asynchronous (also just to note, you don't need the `draw()` here - just the `load()`).

Comment: thnks a lot, it's working now

Comment: Great! You can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for future visitors.